# How to add condition to only one layout update action in Oro CRM?

Tags: orocrm, orocommerce

I want to apply action in layout update file by specific condition. I know, we can add condition to whole layout update file with `conditions` property. But can we apply a condition for a certain action, e.g.:

```
layout:
    actions:
        - '@someAction':
        ...
        - '@move':
            id: id
            parentId: parent_id
            condition: 'context["some_condition"]'
```

I know, there is no `condition` property for specific layout update action, but maybe there is some way to achieve same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only option here - is to move the single action with the condition to a separate layout update YAML file. You can place it in the same folder with a different name.

Comment: Yes, I've done it the way you explained, however it is rather hacky way, I guess this should be implemented in layout updates engine.

Comment: It's expected behavior. Conditions work on a file-level only.